# 4.7 Utils/Mail.php doesn't check if CC/BCC are null but should

Tags: email

Acc'ding to Civi documentation, PEAR packages needed by Civi are included w/the install, so the mailer functionality is determined by Civi.
I am running Civi for WP v 4.7.20 with PHP 5.6.16 and Apache 2.4
System mail setting is mail() - the mail 'test' works because only 'from','to','subject' and 'message' are set.  But system mail (e.g. registration mail or ad hoc mail sent to event participant) fails.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: replace current lines in Utils/Mail.php where no check for null CC, BCC is made, with the following (line 194 +) from older version of Mail.php:

```
if (CRM_Utils_Array::value('cc', $params) != NULL){
  $headers['Cc'] = CRM_Utils_Array::value('cc', $params);
}
if (CRM_Utils_Array::value('bcc', $params) != NULL){
  $headers['Bcc'] = CRM_Utils_Array::value('bcc', $params);
}
```

I don't know why the code was changed to not check for null. It seems it doesn't hurt to check, and if null CC/BCC are put into headers, mail() fails.

Comment: Which "older" version of `Utils/Mail.php` were you looking at? It [doesn't look like those lines changed recently to me](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blame/master/CRM/Utils/Mail.php), assuming we're talking about the same - `CRM/Utils/Mail.php` in civicrm-core.

Comment: I'd be asking: Why is this specific server / site putting `null` into those values? And, do other sites *not* do that? It would be worth reporting this issue over on JIRA (https://issues.civicrm.org) if you can reproduce it, that way you can get a fix upstream (and avoid future patching), or identify the underlying issue specific to this site (and address a cause which only affects this instance).